# create a new dataframes with rows from another dataframe with specific columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a new pandas dataframe from an existing dataframe with only rows where specific columns values are bigger than x.
For example:

```
df =   A B C
     0 1 0 2
     1 2 1 3
     2 3 3 0
     3 4 2 5
```

I want to create new_df with only the rows where the values of columns B and C are bigger than 0 which means

```
new_df =  A B C
        0 2 1 3
        1 4 2 5
```

I used the command :

```
new_df = df.loc[df['B'] > 0 & df['C'] > 0]
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: ``df.loc[df.B.gt(0) & df.C.gt(0), :]`` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it. Use parenthesis to enclose conditions:

```
new_df = df.loc[(df['B'] > 0) & (df['C'] > 0)]
```

The binary operators `&` and `|` take precedence over equalities/inequalities. So what you were doing was equivalent to:

```
new_df = df.loc[(df['B'] > (0 & df['C'])) > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
df[(df[['B', 'C']] > 0).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
1  2  1  3
3  4  2  5
```